# Making app title Italic

Tags: ios, objective-c

Just curious, is it possible to make app name in italic?

The app name is My Bar where I want Bar to appear in italic.

### My *Bar*

Comment: No, you can not do it with IOS SDK because apple is not allowing that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that it's not. My evidence is that iTunes Connect does not allow formatting on anything you enter, even the description. Also, if it were possible, I'm sure you or I would have seen it by now.

Comment: it should be comment.

Comment: Why? Doesn't this answer the question?

Comment: @Namo I agree with `woz` this is definitely an answer. As it clearly answers what the user has asked.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible apple dosen't allow this.

Comment: This should be a comment.